# Postgres refuses to insert timestamp value from one table to another table

Tags: postgresql, timestamp-with-timezone

Table foo:

```
create table table_foo
(
    foo_id            integer,
    foo_some_timestamp timestamp without timezone
)
```

Table bar:

```
create table table_bar
(
    bar_id            integer,
    foo_id            integer,
    bar_some_timestamp timestamp without timezone
)
```

When I do an insert like so, it fails:

```
insert into table_bar (foo_id, bar_some_timestamp) (
  select foo_id, foo_some_timestamp as bar_some_timestamp
  from foo
  left join table_bar on table_foo.foo_id = table_bar.foo_id
);
```

But I get an error:

```
column "foo_sime_timestamp" is of type timestamp without time zone but expression is of type text Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
```

I have tried `to_timestamp` which weirdly throws the following error:

```
to_timestamp(foo_some_timestamp, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24-MI-SS.US')::timestamp without time zone as bar_some_timestamp

 ERROR: function to_timestamp(timestamp without time zone, unknown) does not exist Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Since it's a left join, the result contains a lot of null values. But using `COALESCE` yields the same errors.

What am I missing?
(Postgres v11)

Comment: `integer autoincrement,` is invalid for Postgres

Comment: Your `CREATE` names first table `table_foo` but you `SELECT` from `foo`. Those are two different tables.

Comment: Fixed the query. I had to obfuscate column names hence had to re-write the query hence the mistakes. tHanks.

Comment: re-edited the question back to the "incorrect query" because that's what the issue was.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your target table has three columns, but your select only provides two. You should always qualify the target columns in an INSERT statement, but if you provide less than than the target table has, this is mandatory. The columns are matched by position, not by name.

```
insert into table_bar (foo_id, bar_some_timestamp)
select tf.foo_id, tf.foo_some_timestamp
from table_foo tf
  left join table_bar tb on tf.foo_id = tb.foo_id
;
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=862ab66a078269e83a732247e4209dd0)

Comment: Turns out my original query was missing a few columns resulting in what you mentioned in your answer. I am going to re-edit my question to reflect the "incorrect query" that I was using so that others know what mistake I was making. Thanks.